# Struggling with a query which is requiring an index

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the local emulator attempting to return results from a geospatial query.  If it wasn't for the fact that I shave my head, I'd be tearing my hair out.  I've described what I'm attempting to do and what I've tried here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79c449c9-4fe7-43cf-ba07-6b168ead60da/struggling-with-this-geospatial-linq-query-?forum=AzureDocumentDB

For the love of all that is holy, if you have a suggestion, please help.  My life is falling apart over here with regard to this stinkin' query.

Thanks for any help any of you can provide.

-r

Comment: I didn't vote your question down for this but others might because it's best to  not have the meat of your question be on the other end of a link. I would recommend that you edit and bring in that content to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do a self-join to flatten the array of devices and use 'ST_DISTANCE()'. It would look something like this.

```
SELECT d.name
FROM users u
JOIN d IN u.devices
WHERE ST_DISTANCE(d.currentLocation, <user location>) < 500
```

Not 100% sure it would use an index but I think it would.

Failing that, there may be another way with a tweak to your schema. Store a denormalized polygon of all the device locations. Then you can generate a polygon that approximates a circle centered where the user is with the specified radius. Then you can compose a query using `ST_INTERSECTS()` with this simulated circle against the denormalized polygon of all devices.

I haven't tried this so I don't know for certain that it will use an index but I think it is highly likely. Also, the composition of your denormalized polygon might be tricky. I'd recommend that you find the center of the devices and make the polygon be a star shape going from each device back to the center or near the center then back out to the next device, etc. This way, it is much less likely to come back with a result where the user location is between two devices but neither is within the specified radius of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the suggestion Larry.  I was actually able to get it working with the query I had.  It turns out I was spoiled by the Azure portal automatically creating a policy for me and the local DocumentDB emulator not.   So I took my Azure created policy and pasted it into my emulator and my last query worked as expected.  For references, here's the policy:

```
{
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
  "indexes": [
    {
      "kind": "Range",
      "dataType": "Number",
      "precision": -1
    },
    {
      "kind": "Range",
      "dataType": "String",
      "precision": -1
    },
    {
      "kind": "Spatial",
      "dataType": "Point"
    }
  ]
}
 ],
 "excludedPaths": []
}
```

Thanks again!  Much appreciated!